# Validate duplicate entry using assert - Symfony/API-Platform

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

When I am creating user, I have managed to validate email (not blank and format).

The problem comes when I type the same email as an another user already have. Symfony will return 500 error with the query (in dev mode) and without query in production mode instead of returning 400 error with some proper description.

In production mode I don´t have even chance to parse the error message to show user that email he entered already exists in the database.

I am surprised that there is no assert for it.

How should I deal with it?

Thank you

Comment: There is assert for it https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: @NikitaU. You are a genius, I really should learn to use google better. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is [an assert for it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

The example in documentation perfectly fit exactly your use case:

```
// src/Entity/User.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// DON'T forget the following use statement!!!
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    protected $email;
}
```